# How to specify command line arguments within build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

There are a number of Q&A about how to send command line args `to sbt run` . My question is: how to specify the command line args in a hard-coded manner within `build.sbt` - where we know how to specify the class itself:

```
mainClass in Global := Some("mypackage.MyMainClas")
```

We need to specify the command line parameters in a hardcoded manner in `build.sbt` due to our toolchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try create custom `run` task with the **default arguments**, like:

```
lazy val myParameters = Array("arg1", "arg3")
lazy val myRunTask = taskKey[Unit]("A custom run task.")
fullRunTask(myRunTask, Runtime, "mypackage.MyMainClas", myParameters: _*)
```

and run with: `sbt myRunTask`.

Reference:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#How+can+I+create+a+custom+run+task%2C+in+addition+to+%3F